# How to POST a Multipart form with image and a JSON object containing an array of objects using CURL

Tags: arrays, json, shell, curl

I am trying to post the following JSON object alongside with image data using curl:

```
{
  "score_id": "153A6D67",
  "inputs": [{
    "type": "hits",
    "value": "4"
  },{
    "type": "miss",
    "value": "3"
  }]
}
```

The best I have come so far is this:

```
curl --request POST "https://my-server/post-url" \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--form "score_id=153A6D67" \
--form 'inputs[]={"type":"hits","value":"4"}; type=application/json' \
--form 'inputs[]={"type":"miss","value":"3"}; type=application/json' \
--form "uploaded_image=@$IMAGE"   # <<< IMPORTANT! this is an image!
```

The server implementation I am trying to hit, does not recognize the objects sent with the attribute `inputs`.
Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much for any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

```
curl --request POST "https://my-server/post-url" \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--form "score_id=153A6D67" \
--form 'inputs[0][type]=hits' \
--form 'inputs[0][value]=4' \
--form 'inputs[1][type]=miss' \
--form 'inputs[1][value]=3' \
--form "uploaded_image=@$IMAGE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://my-server/post-url' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "score_id": "153A6D67",
  "inputs": [{
    "type": "hits",
    "value": "4"
  },{
    "type": "miss",
    "value": "3"
  }]
}'
```

Comment: Thank your for your response, but this won't allow a multi-part form! See the my last line: --form "uploaded_image=@$IMAGE"

Comment: Pass image string as base64 encoded format